# C++: pass variable by value

Tags: c++

This is the situation:

```
int f(int a){
    ...
    g(a);
    ...
}

void g(int a){...}
```

The problem is that the compiler says that there is no matching function for call to g(int&). It wants me to pass the variable by reference and g() recieves parameters by value.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What happens if you switch the definitions of `f` and `g` round?

Comment: Are you sure that's the right code?  The function f returns an int, but there is no return statement.

Comment: can you post the compiler error ?

Comment: Maybe your function f() doesn't know that the function g() exits. Did you forget to forward declare g()? Or switch f() and g() around like Dominic suggested.

Comment: Well the `int&` in the call doesn't mean you are required to pass `a` by reference. It's just showing you the arguments you passed, which are `g(lvalue int)`. Since it cannot express lvalue-ness by means of a type, it shows `g(int&)` instead.

Comment: litb: So why is the compiler showing an error? How can I pass the value inside 'a' as an argument?

Comment: If your code really looked the way you posted it, the compiler would not "want you to pass the variable by reference". It would simply tell you that it doesn't know what `g` is. Either the code you posted is bogus or the compiler behavior you are describing is bogus. Please, provide a meaningful decription of the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, there's not much here, but the first thing is: make sure you have a declaration for g that's included before f is defined.

```
void g(int a);
```

Otherwise, when you get to f, function f has no idea what function g looks like, and you'll run into trouble. From what you've given so far, that's the best I can say.

Comment: yes, it is. If I declared g() as: g(int& a); it would work, but that's not what I want to do.

Comment: @macaco: I think you need to post some more code then. What you have posted will not invoke any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `g()` needs to be defined above `f()`

Comment: You mean *declared*. The compiler looks for the existence of functions, and later links to the actual implementation (the *definition*).

Comment: yes that would also work, but if it is simple function better *define* it it above

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong:

1) g is not declared before it is used, so the compiler will compain about that. Assuming you fixed that issue, then the next issue is:

2) f is not returning an int.